# String.replace with regular expression

Tags: c#, string

```
string s = "Text1 Text2 08/13/2014 08:17:22";
```

How can I take the string "text1 text2" and remove the DateTime?

I would like to get 1 string that has the value of "text1 text2"

Note, the text can be any text, the time can be any time but with the same DateTime Format

Comment: Any attempt? Text1 and Text2 are always single words space separated?

Comment: Is is always in that format? Is it always the last part of the string? Or do you always want the first two words? ...

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. It's pretty clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 2):

> Note, the text can be any text, the time can be any time but with the
>   same DateTime Format

You could simply use `String.Remove`:

```
string result = s.Remove(s.Length - 19).Trim(); // skipped s.Length >= 19 check
```

Comment: Because the date-time string is 19 chars long

Comment: @Neel: yes, because OP mentioned that the text is variable but the format of the `DateTime` is strict. So the rule is: remove 19 characters from the end (`"08/13/2014 08:17:22".Length`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use string.Substring?

```
string text = s.Substring(0, s.Length - "08/13/2014 08:17:22".Length);
via regex
string text = Regex.Match(s, @"([\s\S]*)\s?\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Doesn't it need a '$' in there to indicate the end of the string match?

Comment: It's not necessary in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can always delete ending symbols.

```
s = s.Remove(s.Length-19);//19 is length of dates.
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code I have tested in Visual studio and it works :-

```
 string s = string.Empty;
 string result = string.Empty;
 s = "Text1 Text2 08/13/2014 08:17:22";
 string[] split = s.Split(' ');
 foreach (string i in split.Take(2))
 {
      result += i;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# code using regular expression:

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(s, @" \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}", "");
```